# Forgot samsung tablet password

Tags: factory-reset, locked-out

So on my samsung tab, it is turned on and i forgot the password, I cant reset it with find my phone because it needs to be connected to a reset, I also cant factory reset it because it is already turned on, what do I do?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! For starters, our [locked-out tag wiki](/tags/locked-out/info) has helpful links.

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch it off by pressing : <kbd>Power</kbd>+<kbd>Volume</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>home</kbd> for almost 13 seconds
2. Go to recovery mode by pressing: <kbd>Power</kbd>+<kbd>Volume Up</kbd> + <kbd>home</kbd> for around 6 seconds

Here you can factory reset it, of course you have your credentials (email & password)

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help.